Narrator says "Just because I'm telling you this story, doesn't mean I'm alive at the end"
I'm willing to take a hit on this one because I only remember a single quote, but it's a significant quote so I'm going to ask.
The movie starts off narrated (don't recall if it continues throughout or if it's just start/end). In the beginning narration, the quote is: 

"Just because I'm telling you this story, doesn't mean I'm alive at
  the end".

I believe it's a female character who says this. It's going to be an american movie, not foreign. English and probably no earlier than 2003 but I'm only guessing. Feels like it might be an action movie.

No offense, DD, but have you Googled it? Because it spits out Savages from 2012.
It's the first sentence in its trailer, spoken by Blake Lively:



